# Hide compile warnings during test runs

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jestjs

We're building a react app in vscode, using jest to run unit tests.

When we run tests, we're seeing compiler warnings for files in node_modules.

```
PASS  src/components/Common/IonicWrappers/__tests__/KorSelect.test.tsx
PASS  src/components/Common/IonicWrappers/__tests__/KorHeader.test.tsx
● Console

console.warn node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11494
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.
```

We run our tests with `npm test`, where package,json contains:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test-react": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!(@ionic|ionicons|capacitor-data-storage-sqlite))\"",
    "test": "npm run test-react",
    [...]
},
```

And .vscode/settings.json is:

```
{
    "jest.pathToJest": "--runInBand --no-cache --watchAll=false --transformIgnorePatterns='node_modules/(?!(@ionic|ionicons|capacitor-data-storage-sqlite))'",
    "jest.runAllTestsFirst": false,
    "jest.enableInlineErrorMessages": false,
    "jest.pathToConfig": "./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
    "jestrunner.jestCommand": "npm test --runInBand --no-cache --watchAll=false --transformIgnorePatterns='node_modules/(?!(@ionic|ionicons|capacitor-data-storage-sqlite))'"
}
```

Now these warnings are valuable, and we do need to know that there are packages in node_modules that we might want to consider updating, but I don't need to see them on every test run.

And they make it hard to see the actual results of the tests.

Is there anyway to configure things to suppress them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#silent

> --silent
>
> Prevent tests from printing messages through the console.